# Is my alternate definition of scc in the lambda calculus correct?

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

`scc` is a combinator (successor) that takes a Church Numeral n and returns another Church numeral.

We have in mind that church numerals are defined as follows:

```
c_0 = λs. λz. z;
c_1 = λs. λz. s z;
c_2 = λs. λz. s (s z);
c_3 = λs. λz. s (s (s z));
...
```

scc may be defined:

```
scc = λn. λs. λz. s (n s z);
```

Is the definition:

```
scc' = λn. λs. c_1 s n;
```

equivalent?

```
scc' = λn. λs. c_1 s n;
      λn. λs. (λs. λz. s z) s n;
      λn. λs. s n;
```

so when `scc'` is applied to a church numeral, this results:

```
foo = scc' c_2
    = (λn. λs. s n) c_2
    = s c_2
    = s (s (s z))
    = c_3
```

Comment: Where did `s` come from in `scc = λn. λz. s (n s z);`?

Comment: I missed it during transcription

Answer (score 1):

No.  By beta reduction:

```
scc' = λn. λs. c_1 s n;
     = λn. λs. (λs. λz. s z) s n
     = λn. λs. (λz. s z) n
     = λn. λs. s n
```

More generally, for any church numeral `x`

```
x = λn. λs. x s n
```

which can be proven by induction or by observing that it is just a double application of eta contraction.

EDIT: expanding to explain how this all works.

How do we know church numerals are correct?  Well, imagine you extended the lambda calculus with numbers and basic arithmetic.  Then define the following function

```
fromChurch = λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0
```

I claim that `fromChurch` converts from church numerals to numbers in the way you would expect

```
fromChurch c_0 
  = (λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0) (λs. λz. z) 
  = (λs. λz. z) (λn. n + 1) 0)
  = (λz. z) 0
  = 0
fromChurch c_1 
  = (λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0) (λs. λz. s z)
  = (λs. λz. s z) (λn. n + 1) 0
  = (λz. (λn. n + 1) z) 0
  = (λn. n + 1) 0
  = 0 + 1
  = 1
fromChurch c_2 
  = (λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0) (λs. λz. s (s z))
  = (λs. λz. s (s z)) (λn. n + 1) 0
  = (λz. (λn. n + 1) ((λn. n + 1) z) 0
  = (λn. n + 1) ((λn. n + 1) 0)
  = ((λn. n + 1) 0) + 1
  = (0 + 1) + 1
  = 2
```

the succesor function then looks like (note, you were missing the `λs`)

```
scc = λn. λs. λz. s (n s z)
```

here is the correctness condition for the `succesor function`

```
fromChurch (scc x)
  = (λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0) ((λn. λs. λz. s (n s z)) x)
  = (λn. λs. λz. s (n s z)) x (λn. n + 1) 0
  = (λs. λz. s (x s z)) (λn. n + 1) 0
  = (λz. (λn. n + 1) (x (λn. n + 1) z)) 0
  = (λn. n + 1) (x (λn. n + 1) 0)
  = (x (λn. n + 1) 0) + 1
  = ((λc. c (λn. n + 1) 0) x) + 1 
  = (fromChurch x) + 1
```

note the second to last step was a beta expansion instead of a beta reduction.

The point though is that `scc` really does compute a church numeral whose integer value is one higher.

On the other hand `λn. λs. c_1 s n` is not a function from church numerals to church numeras...it is just a church numeral.  Indeed, it is the church numeral value of `1`.  In no way does it take the successor.

EDIT 2:

the reduction sequence you give

```
foo = scc' c_2
 = (λn. λs. s n) c_2
 = s c_2
 = s (s (s z))
 = c_3
```

is not quite correct

```
(λn. λs. s n) c_2
 = λs. s c_2
```

and that is done since `λs. s c_2` is a normal form and thus not equal to `c_3`.